# How can I calculate days between two dates in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to calculate days between two dates

this is my code now:

```
int daysBetween(DateTime from, DateTime to) {
  from = DateTime(from.year, from.month, from.day);
  to = DateTime(to.year, to.month, to.day);
  return (to.difference(from).inHours / 24).round();
}
```

I call this with:

```
final difference = daysBetween(
  today,
  example[index].date,
);
```

This code works good, but I would like use a variable instead "example[index].date"
Because I need to calculate with another dates.

omething like this:

```
final difference = daysBetween(
  today,
  date,
)
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Just declare a new variable `DateTime date = ...;` and call the function again using `daysBetween(today, date)`. Is that what you mean?

Comment: How can I do that if my "example[index].date' can be something like "example[index].date2" and "example[index].date3" and so on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it.

This is my solution:

I call my Function in my code and use my value respectively.

Example:

```
BorderSide(color: daysBetween(today, example.date) <= 0
 ? Colors.deepOrange
 : Colors.green,
)

Container(color: daysBetween(today, example.date2) <= 0
 ? Colors.deepOrange
 : Colors.green,
)
```

And so on...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).